# Converting images to grey scale in Python

Tags: python, html, css, image, image-processing

```
class PPM(object):
    def __init__(self, infile, outfile):
        self.infile=infile
        self.outfile=outfile

        #Read in data of image
        data= open(self.infile,"r")
        datain=data.read()
        splits=datain.split()

        #Header info
        self.type=splits[0]
        self.columns=splits[1]
        self.row=splits[2]
        self.colour=splits[3]
        self.pixels=splits[4:]

    def greysscale():
            for row in range(rows):
                for column in range(columns):
                    r, g, b = image.getPixel(row, column)
                    brightness = int(round(0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b))
                    image.setPixel(row, column, color_rgb(brightness, brightness, brightness))


    def flattenred():
        for colour in range (0,len(self.pixels),3):
            self.pixels [colour]=str[0]

        return picture

    def writetofile(self):
        dataout= open(self.outfile,"w")
        dataout.write(self.type +"\n" + self.columns + "\n" + self.row +"\n"+ self.colour +"\n"+ " ".join (self.pixels))


sample= PPM("cake.ppm", "Replica.ppm")
sample.writetofile()
```

I am having trouble writing a function called grey_scale which will change the picture into a grey scale image by averaging the values of all three color numbers for a pixel, the red, green and blue, and then replacing them all by that average.
So if the three colors were 25, 75 and 250, the average would be 116, and all three numbers would become 116.
How would I do this?

Comment: I'm assuming you're not allowed to use [`PIL`/`Pillow`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org) for this, right?

Comment: What was wrong with the answer i gave here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21031546/image-flipping-and-editing-in-python/21033093#21033093

Comment: @M4rtini- I don't understand any of it, nor am I allowed to use PIL/Pillow/numpy and I am only 12 so I don't have an advanced understanding of Python and Image editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rom_file= [0,3,1]
#Main Function which adds s dots and xs to the deck list(s) depending on the data input file
def main():
    #Container for the output of the program, each nested list contains one row of the output
    decks = [[], [], [], [], []]
    #list that contains the number of empty rows for inputs 1-5(location of input given by [each - 1])
    empty_rows = [4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
    #Scan through each element of the list
    for each in from_file:
        #If the element 'each' is equal to 0, append a single dot to all 5 rows
        if each == 0:
            for i in range(5):
                decks[i].append('.')
        #If the input is in the range 1-5, define variables and the nested for loops
        else:
            #Maximum width of each pyramid
            max = (each * 2) - 1
            half_dots = int((max - 1) / 2)
            base_x = 1
            loc = each - 1
            #For loop that appends the max. number of dots to rows depending on data in empty_rows
            for every in range(empty_rows[loc]):
                decks[every].append(max * '.')
            #Primary for loop; appends the dots and xs to any row not covered by the previous loop (ALl rows that do not already have max dots) for each between 1-5
            for i in range(each):
                decks[i + empty_rows[loc]].append(half_dots * '.')
                decks[i + empty_rows[loc]].append(base_x * 'x')
                decks[i + empty_rows[loc]].append(half_dots * '.')
                half_dots -= 1
                base_x += 2
    #A loop that print out the results
    for each in decks:
        text = ""
        for i in each:
            text += i
        print(text)


#Starts the program by calling the main function
main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the *hard* part right, there are just a lot of other little things you need to deal with.

Your first problem is that you never actually call the `greysscale` function anywhere, so whatever you put there won't do any good. Most likely you wanted something like this at the end:

```
sample = PPM("cake.ppm", "Replica.ppm")
sample.greysscale()
sample.writetofile()
```

You've also misspelled `grey_scale`, both leaving out the `_` and adding an extra `s`, so if your teacher is a stickler you might get marked off for that.

Your next problem is that a method has to take a `self` parameter. You've done this properly for `__init__` and `writetofile`; you just need to do the same thing here.

Next, you're trying to use variables `rows` and `columns` and `image` that don't exist anywhere. You have *similar* values available as `self.row`, `self.columns`, and `self.pixels`, but you have to use the values you actually have, not similar ones.

`self.row` and `self.columns` are strings, not numbers; you need to convert them with `int`. While we're at it, it's much clearer to call the first one `self.rows`.

And `pixels` seems to be an array of strings, separated on spaces. That's actually not useful at all. If you look at a PPM file, after the first three lines, it's just raw binary data. Any spaces in there just mean that some color happens to have the value 32, which isn't exactly meaningful. So you need to only split off the first four values, then leave the rest alone as one big string of bytes.

You definitely can't call methods like `getPixel` or `setPixel` on that string. It's just a bunch of bytes; it has no idea what that means. Each pixel is three bytes, one per color; the columns just come one right after the other, and the rows one right after the other. So, to get the pixel at `row, column`, the red color is at `row * self.columns * 3 + column * 3`, and the green and blue are the next two. You can use a slice to get all three bytes at once. But, since this is just a string of bytes, each of those will be a character; you need to call `ord` on them to get the byte numbers, and then `chr` to turn them back. Plus, you're not allowed to mutate a string in-place. But there's a nice trick we can use to fix all of those problems—a `bytearray` is like a string, except that it's mutable, and its elements are numbers instead of single-byte strings.

Meanwhile, you want to use `"".join`, not `" ".join`, or you'll add an extra space between each byte, which will break the file. But you really don't need that—it's already a `bytearray`, which can be used like a string.

And finally, once you've got all those individual split bits as integers instead of strings, you can't just concatenate them anymore. It'll be a lot easier to do this with `format` than to manually convert them back to strings just to concatenate them up. Also, PPM files generally put a space, not a newline, between the rows and columns.

While we're at it, you need to `close` the files you open—especially for files you're writing; otherwise, there's no guarantee that the last block of data will ever get flushed to disk—and you should open binary files in binary mode.

So:

```
class PPM(object):
    def __init__(self, infile, outfile):
        self.infile=infile
        self.outfile=outfile

        #Read in data of image
        data= open(self.infile,"r")
        datain=data.read()
        splits=datain.split(None, 4)

        #Header info
        self.type=splits[0]
        self.columns=int(splits[1])
        self.rows=int(splits[2])
        self.colour=int(splits[3])
        self.pixels=bytearray(splits[4])

    def grey_scale(self):
            for row in range(self.rows):
                for column in range(self.columns):
                    start = row * self.columns * 3 + column * 3
                    end = start + 3
                    r, g, b = self.pixels[start:end]
                    brightness = int(round(0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b))
                    self.pixels[start:end] = brightness, brightness, brightness

    def writetofile(self):
        dataout= open(self.outfile, "wb")
        dataout.write('{}\n{} {}\n{}\n{}'.format(self.type, 
                                                 self.columns, self.rows, 
                                                 self.colour, 
                                                 self.pixels))

sample = PPM("cake.ppm", "Replica.ppm")
sample.grey_scale()
sample.writetofile()
```

---

If you want to use a different brightness formula, that's easy—just change the line that computes the brightness, like this:

```
brightness = int(round((r+g+b)/3.0))
```

---

If you actually have plain-PPM files rather than normal PPM files (in which case… wow, I've never seen one in the wild), then you were closer on track with your parsing code, but still missing one key element.

You can go back to `splits = detain.split()`, then `splits[4:]` will be a sequence of all of the pixel-color values… but it will be a sequence of those pixel-color values *as strings*. If you want them as integers, you need to call [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) on each one, which you can do with a list comprehension or a [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) call, like:

```
self.pixels=map(int, splits[4:])
```

Then you've got a sequence of numbers, just like a `bytearray`, so all of that code can be the same… up until output, where you want to convert them back into whitespace-separated strings to create a new plain-PPM. Your original `join` almost works, except that you can't join integers; you have to convert them back to strings first. Again, you can do this by using `map` on the [`str`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str) function:

```
pixelstring = " ".join(map(str, self.pixels))
dataout.write('{}\n{} {}\n{}\n{}'.format(self.type, 
                                         self.columns, self.rows, 
                                         self.colour, 
                                         pixelstring))
```

Comment: I need to do this using the formula brightness = int(round( (r + g + b) / 3 ))

Comment: how can i change the greyscale formula so that  brightness = int(round( (r + g + b) / 3 ))

Comment: @abarnert- Also,  in the writetofunction, on the dataout.write line why did you insert {}. What did you do on the dataout.write line

Comment: @abarnert The images given for his assignment, from the link given in his first question, do in fact have the pixels as a string of values separated by spaces. It appears to be a plain PPM, as defined here: http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html

Comment: @mmA for the brightness formula replacing the line with what you wrote there should be enough. Simply change the 3 at the end into 3.0 to get float division. Those {} in the write function get's replaced by the arguments of the format function.

Comment: @mmA: If you need details more than M4rtini's explanation, See [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

Answer (score 0):

I see you are doing a YCrCb conversion in your line:

```
brightness = int(round(0.299 * r + 0.587 * g + 0.114 * b))
```

Just change this to:

```
brightness = int(round( (r + g + b) / 3 ))
```

#### Edit

I should add that the way you have is actually a better way to do the conversion (although technically you are creating luminance and not brightness). The result is more in tune with how the human eye perceives grays. Here is a fairly easy to read link on the subject - http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/ You can see how the luminosity conversion looks better. The conversion you were using (YCrCb) is close to this, unfortunately you will have to get someone with more expertees to tell you the exact difference though.

#### Edit2

Just looking at @abarnert's answer, I didn't realise what you had was a full program. You should follow his advice for improving it as a whole.